# How to eliminate duplicate entries from SAS dataset?

Tags: csv, sas

There is a sample dataset provided to me in CSV format.
the dummy dataset is as follows:

```
Baseball1,Baseball2
USA,France
USA,Italy
USA,England
England,USA
England,Australia
England,Sri Lanka
France,USA
France,England
France,Italy
Italy,USA
Italy,France
Italy,England
```

i need to get an output data in which the data has descrete values only.
desired output is like:

```
Baseball1   Baseball2
  USA        France
  USA        Italy
  USA       England
 England    Australia
 England    Sri Lanka
 France     England
 France      Italy
 Italy      England
```

i think that PROC SQL might work here but i am not sure of how to remove duplicate entries of different columns.

Comment: Interesting problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tricky part is that you care about the horizontal order of variables, so for you France/Italy and Italy/France actually forms a duplicate that you want to remove.

See my code below with notes on what it does:

```
/* Reading data in */
data have; 
length baseball1 $ 9 baseball2 $ 9; 
infile datalines delimiter=',';
input Baseball1 $ Baseball2 $ ; 
datalines; 
USA,France
USA,Italy
USA,England
England,USA
England,Australia
England,Sri Lanka
France,USA
France,England
France,Italy
Italy,USA
Italy,France
Italy,England
;

/* horizontal sorting */
data sorted_arrays; 
set have; 
length Team1 $ 9 Team2 $ 9; 
/* Copying data into new vars to preserve original data for output */
Team1 = Baseball1;
Team2 = Baseball2;
/* Sorting data horizontally with sortc call */
call sortc(Team1,Team2); 
/* Creating an ID by concatenating sorted variables */ 
ID = (CATX("/",Team1,Team2)); 
/* Preserving original order */ 
order = _N_; 
run; 

/* Removing duplicates by ID and keeping required variables*/ 
PROC SORT data=sorted_arrays out=no_dupes(keep=baseball1 baseball2 order) NODUPKEY; 
BY ID; 
RUN;

/* Returning to original order to achieve the result needed */
PROC SORT data=no_dupes out=want(drop=order); 
by order; 
run;  

/* Final Report*/
PROC PRINT data=want;
RUN;
```

Result:

[image]

If final horizontal/vertical order of variables doesn't matter, you can simplify code as follows and you can use PROC SQL:

```
/* Reading data in */
data have; 
length baseball1 $ 9 baseball2 $ 9; 
infile datalines delimiter=',';
input Baseball1 $ Baseball2 $ ; 
/* horizontal sorting */
call sortc(Baseball1,Baseball2); 
datalines; 
USA,France
USA,Italy
USA,England
England,USA
England,Australia
England,Sri Lanka
France,USA
France,England
France,Italy
Italy,USA
Italy,France
Italy,England
;

/*Remove dupes */
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE want AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.baseball1, 
          t1.baseball2
      FROM WORK.HAVE t1;
QUIT;


/* Final Report*/
PROC PRINT data=want;
RUN;
```

Result:

[image]

```
/* Reading data in */
data have (drop=tmp);
    length baseball1 $ 9 baseball2 $ 9 tmp $9;
    infile datalines delimiter=',';
    input Baseball1 $ Baseball2 $;

    /* horizontal sorting */
    if Baseball1>Baseball2 then
        do;
            tmp = Baseball1;
            Baseball1=Baseball2;
            Baseball2 = tmp;
        end;

    datalines;
USA,France
USA,Italy
USA,England
England,USA
England,Australia
England,Sri Lanka
France,USA
France,England
France,Italy
Italy,USA
Italy,France
Italy,England
;

/*Remove dupes */
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE want AS 
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.baseball1, 
            t1.baseball2
        FROM WORK.HAVE t1;
QUIT;

/* Final Report*/
PROC PRINT data=want;
RUN;
```

Same result as in previous example:

[image]

Comment: Well i am not concerned with the order at all. it can shor France USA or either USA France. Anyone entry is accepted. Thanks

Comment: You have put a desired dataset in your question which had order horizontally and vertically preserved. If you don't care about order, the code will still work you. You can simplify it by removing half of id. I will amend my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: what if i don't want to use the CALL Sortc function?

Comment: If you don't want to use the `call sortc`, you can always build your own logic for horizontal sorting. A standard larger then comparison works with character strings just as well. You could then do the horizontal sorting in `proc sql`. Could I ask you what exactly prevents you from implementing `sortc`?

Comment: i want to learn the basic behind the 'sortc' . you may say i am just keen to know. @VasilijNevlev

Comment: I have put another version in where I am using greater then logic to sort items horizontally which produces exactly the same result as with call sortc but with 5 more lines of codes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101592/discussion-between-desmond-carros-and-vasilij-nevlev).